# Merge tags [hg-convert] and [mercurial-convert]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [hg-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg-convert) and [mercurial-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial-convert) are for the same Mercurial feature.

Though the [hg-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg-convert) tag is more widely used, the main Mercurial tag is [mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial) and so for consistency I think [mercurial-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial-convert) should be the one to retain. It would be useful if [hg-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg-convert) can redirect (synonym?) to that one.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping [mercurial-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial-convert) as the main tag has another minute advantage. It has a tag wiki (But yeah, it is plagiarized, which is sad ... so we have to rewrite it anyway)

The problem with doing this directly is that [hg-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg-convert) is used more widely, and therefore, I get the error that I can't create a synonym. The workaround here is to create a synonym in the opposite way and swap them.

I did it now, and they are synonyms. That is [hg-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg-convert) (x 50) → [mercurial-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial-convert) (x 9). I will wait for a few days and then merge the tags.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of this!